# Remoting a 3D printer using netcat or socat

Tags: networking, sharing, devices, serial-port

I have my 3D printer at my lab in the basement, where I also have my Ubuntu (desktop) fileserver; in order to not overload it, I would like to avoid the simplest solution that's run Cura on fileserver (or dedicated PC) via Remmina;
I looked for sharing/remoting ttyUSB port across LAN, finding similar requests, but I'm getting lost with netcat/socat parameters (I'm not so skilled at Ubuntu/linux and networking indeed)
I think socat can be the right way; any other solution not involving 3rd party software is welcome

to recap:

3Dprinter <-> fileserver ttyUSB <-> socat <-> LAN <-> socat <-> myPC virtual ttyUSB <-> Cura3D

thank you in advance, greetings

Comment: We don't know what is "simplest" to you. Depends upon your experience and skills. Personally, I remote-control my printer using Octoprint in an LXD container because that's "simplest" for me. If you REALLY want to control USB across a network, look into USBIP (it's in the Ubuntu repositories). It's a simple client/server that uses your existing network stack and does not require socat nor netcat. I've seen USBIP clients for Windows, but never tried those -- cross-platform makes things non-simple.